# Number decrement by one from n to 0 PHP

Tags: php, numbers, decrement

I need code which decrements number from 100 to 0 by one with reload. Well we have 100, then reload, then we have 99,...reload...then 98... reload...then 97....and up to zero.

I don't need something like these:

```
for ($n = 101; $n <= 101 and $n > 0 ; $n--) {
    echo '<p>'.($n - 1).'</p>'
}
```

Only one number need to be shown on reload.

Comment: have a look at sessions

Comment: start session, if counter key doesn't exist in session, create key with 100 value else decrement the key.. have a check if counter reaches 0, show some message

Comment: Should the countdown to be per user or shared for all users?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Two users play game. When one loses all cards (numbers) he wins

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sometimes player can lose two cards, but never more than this.

Comment: You will need to store the counter in some storage like a database or cache. Then you fetch the counter, decrease it and update the storage. Start there and come back if you have other questions along the way. Currently, the question is becoming too broad when you're adding more rules etc. without having any code yourself yet.

Answer (score 1):

Start session, if counter key doesn't exist in session, create key with 100 value else decrement the key.. have a check if counter reaches 0, show some message

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['counter'])){

   if($_SESSION['counter']==0){
   die('you have reached to value 0');
   }
   else{ 
   $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter']-1;
   }
}
else{
   $_SESSION['counter'] = 100;
}
```

This is user wise, if you want to maintain a counter for all users keep the counter value in database and keep updating that value.